# asp.net listbox validation pass without a value selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, listbox

I have a listbox with Data coming from a database. But the validation passes even when value is not selected.
I have tried ,just simple required field validator and does not work either.
Here is the code.

```
           <asp:Panel ID="panelDelivery" runat="server"  Visible="false" 
               style="position: relative; top: -130px; background-color: #66FF33; left: 0px;"  >
           <asp:Label ID="lblOverWeight" runat="server" Width="344px"></asp:Label><br />
           <asp:ListBox ID="listBxDelivery" runat="server" DataSourceID="Delivery" 
               DataTextField="DataText" DataValueField="Price" Width="489px"         
               AppendDataBoundItems="True" CausesValidation="True" AutoPostBack="True" 
                   style="top: 0px; left: 0px">
           </asp:ListBox>
```

```
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDelivery" runat="server"
                   ErrorMessage="* Select Delivery " ControlToValidate="listBxDelivery"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: RequiredFieldValidator will only work if there is no data in the control. Since you are talking about selecting from listbox you might need a customValidator and then perform check there.

Answer (score 0):

By default requiredFieldValidator will compare its initialValue(default is "") and ControlToValidate selected value.  make sure you not set the listbox selectedvalue, if you change it also change the initial value of the requiredFieldValidator. 
See examples below

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" ></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2" ></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2" ></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ListBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"    ErrorMessage="Error, Select value" ControlToValidate="ListBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

or

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2" ></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="ListBox1" InitialValue="1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```